# Why does @ConfigurationProperties need getters?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, instantiation, configurationproperties

I realized a strange behavior in SpringBoot.

In a yml file I have the following configuration:

```
main:
  record-id:
    start-position: 1
    value: 1
    enabled: true
  record-name:
    start-position: 2
    value: main
    enabled: true
  invented:
    start-position: 3
    value: 01012020
    enabled: false
```

And these are the classes for it:

```
public class FieldType {
  private Integer startPosition;
  private String value;
  private Boolean enabled;
  getters/setters
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "main")
public class Main {
  private FieldType recordId;
  private FieldType recordName;
  private FieldType invented;
  getters/setters <-- sometimes without getters
}
```

As you can see, the main class has **@ConfigurationProperties** annotation to load the properties from yml into that bean.

And here is what I have found:

1. if I **don't provide getters for** the fields in the **main** class, then sometimes the fields in the main call stay null, so not initiated
2. if I restart the SpringBoot, then randomly other (1 or more) fields stay null, so not initiated
3. if I restart the SpringBoot n times, then, **again and again, random fields stay null**
4. if **I provide getters** for the fields in the main class, then all the **fields will be always instantiated** from tye yml file, no matter how many times I restart SpringBoot

Why is this? Why SpringBoot requires getters for fields which represent properties in yml?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need getter's to bind the properties, you need setters to bind properties if you are using default constructor, [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-java-bean-binding)

> If nested POJO properties are initialized (like the Security field in the preceding example), a setter is not required. If you want the binder to create the instance on the fly by using its default constructor, you need a setter.

In case if you are initializing the `FieldType` in `Main` class, then you don't need setters as well

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "main")
public class Main {
    private FieldType recordId = new FieldType();
    private FieldType recordName = new FieldType();
    private FieldType invented = new FieldType();

 }
```

You can also use [Constructor binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-constructor-binding) by completely avoiding setters

```
public class FieldType {
   private Integer startPosition;
   private String value;
   private Boolean enabled;
   
   public FieldType(Integer startPosition, String value, Boolean enabled) {
         this.startPosition = startPosition;
         this.value = value;
         this.enabled = enabled

  }

  @ConstructorBinding
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "main")
  public class Main {
       private FieldType recordId;
       private FieldType recordName;
       private FieldType invented;

  public Main(FieldType recordId,FieldType recordName,FieldType invented) {
       this.recordId = recordId;
       this.recordName = recordName;
       this.invented = invented;

  }
```

Just a note on Constructor Binding

> To use constructor binding the class must be enabled using @EnableConfigurationProperties or configuration property scanning. You cannot use constructor binding with beans that are created by the regular Spring mechanisms (e.g. @Component beans, beans created via @Bean methods or beans loaded using @Import)

Comment: yes this is how I would imagine also, but during debugging I got different results